# .NET Core application auth with identityserver4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

The authentication part was done using Identity Server 4, now I want to change the `clientId` and `clientSecret`, and use the new credentials, but in the backend I can't find the client configuration and I don't know how it's configured. Could you help me ? Thanks.

I checked the database, there is a table called `ClientSecrets`
there is a `clientId` and a `value` column with hashed value (maybe base64), and other columns also, but I didn't understand what's going on.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Is this from client or server perspective?

Comment: from server perspective